# How can i set a default value to Element UI's transfer component

Tags: components, transfer, element-ui

I am implementing a form to update some database data with laravel and vue js, so i am using the transfer component on element UI.

My question is how can set a default value to both left and right of the component as i already have default data being fetched from DB.

Comment: Add relevant code and show what did you try so far

Comment: I got it already. All i needed to do was pass the data to be shown on the right side of the box list into the v-model array.